# DNS caching and Bind Config

Tags: web, dns, bind

I'm Sys admin of a website. I moved the site to a new server and new IP .config bind for new server but my website Can be seen from the previous server yet , however past 48 hours .
If I navigate to the page on many other device, it takes me to the new server.
what is my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got some cached NS records in your system.

The following methods allow you to remove old and inaccurate DNS information:

**Windows® 8**

1. Press Win+X to open the WinX Menu.
2. Right-click on Command Prompt and select Run as Administrator.
3. Type the following command and press Enter: ipconfig /flushdns

If the command was successful, you will see the following message: Windows IP configuration successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.

**Windows 7**

1. Click the Start button.
2. Enter cmd in the Start menu search field.
3. Right-click on Command Prompt and select Run as Administrator.
4. Type the following command and press Enter: ipconfig /flushdns

If the command was successful, you will see the following message:
Windows IP configuration successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.

**Windows XP, 2000, or Vista®**

1. Click the Start button.
2. On the Start menu, click Run.
3. Type the following command in the Run text box: ipconfig /flushdns

**MacOS® 10.7 and 10.8**

Open Terminal

Type the following command: sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder

Warning: To run this command, you will need to know the computer's Admin account password.

**MacOS 10.5 and 10.6**

Open Terminal

Type the following command: sudo dscacheutil -flushcache

Answer (score 2):

48 hours is more than enough for the domain to propagate. If it still not showing, its something you need to review the dns you have set. try

> dig +trace domain.com

and make sure that its pointing to your new server. dig command only takes less than 30 minutes normally to propagate once you have changed the dns. If that still points to the old server, Then you have set up dns in wrong place.

Check the nameservers of the domain and check where its pointing to. You should edit the dns there.